# Create directive to add warning to form input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to create a directive to add a warning to a form element.

The directive should add an .ng-warning class to input &/or create form.element.$warning object. I want to create the form.element.$warning object so that it works similarly to the form.element.$error object.

How to create an attribute directive that validates a value and passes back a warning via extending the angular form internals?

I've put a plunker here as a template example of how it could be used.
http://plnkr.co/edit/3LkCZKjdozTPaagDojWi?p=preview

The attempt below adds a warning class.

```
app.directive('valMinWarning', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope:false,
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {


        //todo: get form name
        //make access warnings via form.$warnings.prop.warning

        var form = scope.weather; 


        var warnings = form.$warnings;

        if (!warnings)
            warnings = form.$warnings = [];

        if (!warnings[attrs.name])
            warnings.push(attrs.name);

        scope.$watch(function() {
            return ctrl.$modelValue;
        }, function (val) {

            //console.log(scope);

            //console.log("Value " + val);
            if (val < attrs.valMinWarning) {
                warnings[attrs.name] = 'true';
                elm.addClass('ng-warning');
            } else {
                warnings[attrs.name] = 'false';
                elm.removeClass('ng-warning');
            }
        });

    }
};
});
```

Is there an analogous way to add warning validation?

Comment: You have to build it yourself on the same lines as $error. Angular does not have concept of warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer:

The code below is okay as a learning exercise, but tacky because it adds an object 'warnings' to the parent scope. For a more robust solution, extend the angular framework by creating something similar to the [$error](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1621) object.

Sample Use

```
<input type="text" name="measurement" ng-model="myForm.measurment"
    val-min-warning="-10" val-max-warning="100" />

<span ng-show="warnings.measurement.valMinWarning">
    Warning: Measurement less than -10 </span>   

<span ng-show="warnings.measurement.valMaxWarning">
     Warning: Measurement greater than 100 </span>
```

Directives

```
angular.module('myApp.directives').directive('valMinWarning', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope:false,
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

        var warningName = 'valMinWarning';

        AttachWarning(scope, elm, attrs.name, ctrl, warningName,
            function (val) { return parseFloat(val) && parseFloat(val) < attrs.valMinWarning; }    );
    }
};
});


angular.module('myApp.directives').directive('valMaxWarning', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: false,
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        var warningName = 'valMaxWarning';

        AttachWarning(scope, elm, attrs.name, ctrl, warningName,
            function (val) { return parseFloat(val) && parseFloat(val) > attrs.valMaxWarning; }    );
    }
};
});



var WARNING_CLASS = 'ng-warning';
function AttachWarning(scope, elm, elmName, ctrl, warningName, condition) {
//attach 'warning' to scope
//access input element warnings via
// warnings.[elementName].[warningName]
// eg warnings.name.toManyVowels = true;

var warnings = scope.warnings = scope.warnings || {};

if (!warnings[elmName])
    warnings[elmName] = {};

scope.$watch(function () {
    return ctrl.$modelValue;
}, function (val) {        
    if (condition(val)) {
        warnings[elmName][warningName] = 'true';
        elm.addClass(WARNING_CLASS);
    } else {
        warnings[elmName][warningName] = 'false';
        elm.removeClass(WARNING_CLASS);
    }
});
}
```

Relevant Styles

```
<style>
 input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
    border-right: 20px dotted red;
 }

 input.ng-dirty.ng-warning:not(.ng-invalid) {
    border-right: 20px dotted orange;
 }
</style>
```